# How does the logic work for a function that finds the node at which the intersection of two singly linked lists begins?

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, set

The question is Write a program to find the node at which the intersection of two singly linked lists begins. So one solution is below:

```
def getIntersectionNode(self, headA: ListNode, headB: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        visited = set()
        while headA:
            visited.add(headA)
            headA = headA.next
        print(visited)
        while headB:
            if headB in visited: return headB
            headB = headB.next
        return None
```

My question is...how does the logic for this code work?? Because let's say headA = [4,1,8,4,5 ] and headB = [5,6,1,8,4,5] just like in Example 1 below. Now you add every element in the headA linked list into the set, so then the set now has (4, 1, 8, 5) right? Then you loop through the B linked list and check if the current element is in the set. So you start with 5 because that is the beginning of headB. 5 is already in the set, so it should return 5 because "if temp == headA: return headA" but it ends up returning 8, which is correct but why?

For example, the following two linked lists:
[image]

Comment: You need to notice the difference between ```headA``` and ```headA.value```; one is a pointer, the other one is an integer

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Explain this code to me” is not a Stack Overflow issue.
We expect you to show your trace of the code, and ask a *specific* question about a step or feature that confuses you.  Rather than writing out a full example as you've done, you should *test* your assumptions with a few well-placed `print` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken about what `headA` and `headB` are during the iteration in those loops!

These variables don't refer to the **values** stored in the list nodes, but rather to the **list nodes** themselves.

Two distinct nodes can contain the same values, as in your example: Node a1 stores value 4 and Node c2 stores value 4 as well.

Node b1 stores value 5 and node c3 also stores value 5.

But those are distinct nodes! Node b1 is NOT the same as node c3.

With that in mind, now, does it make sense? First you build a set that contains all the **nodes** of list A. So that set is `{a1, a2, c1, c2, c3}`.

Next, you loop through the **nodes** of list B. Is `b1` in the visited set? Nope. What about b2? Nope. What about b3? Nope. Now, what comes in list B after b3? c1!

Is c1 in the visited set? Yes! And as you can see, that's exactly the node we're after.

Comment: great explanation, thank you!